# Use components inside templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

Recently I migrated all the strings in my app to angular-translate. My original strings use components to do some replacements, like this:

`Resource: <get-html value="'dark_matter'"></get-html>`

I noticed that when I put those through the angular-translate filter, the component doesn't get called.

I configured the sanitation strategy to sanitize

`$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');`

And I'm using the filter like this

`<p>{{ 'DESCRIPTION' | translate }}</p>`

The implementation of get-html is the following

`<span ng-bind-html="ct.util.trustHTML(ct.util.getHTML(ct.value))"></span>`

The result is the string without the component replacement.

I would like if it is possible to call a custom component inside a string, or if I'm approaching this from a completely wrong angle.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the getHTML(..) method, you could inject $translate, and do the translation inside the method as so:

`$translate.instant(value)`

Comment: It looks like the component is not being called.